# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors

i know this problem was there before, but i didn't find any solution for me. So - i'm getting this error in Visual Studio 2010.:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class Czas __cdecl data(void)" (?data@@YA?AVCzas@@XZ)

i have main() function, and i have console set in propetites.

and this is my code:

Czas.h

```
#ifndef CZAS_H
#define CZAS_H
class Czas{
private:
    int dzien;
    int miesiac;
    int rok;
public:
    int Dzien() const;
    int Miesiac() const;
    int Rok() const;
    Czas(int dl, int m, int r);
    void Ustaw (int d, int m, int r);
    void Wypisz() const;
    void Wpisz();
    void koryguj();
    int porownaj (const Czas& wzor) const;
};
#endif
```

Czas.cpp

```
#include "Czas.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int dzien;
    int miesiac;
    int rok;
    int Czas::Dzien() const
    {
        return dzien;
    }
    int Czas::Miesiac() const
    {
        return miesiac;
    }
    int Czas::Rok() const
    {
        return rok;
    }
    Czas::Czas(int d=1, int m=1, int r=1970)
    {
        dzien = d;
        miesiac = m;
        rok = r;
        koryguj();
    }
    void Czas::Ustaw (int d, int m, int r)
    {
        dzien = d;
        miesiac = m;
        rok = r;
    }
    void Czas::Wypisz() const
    {
        //wypisujemy dzien;
        if (dzien<10)
            cout<<"0"<<dzien<<".";
        else
            cout<<dzien<<".";
        //wypisujemy miesiac
        if (miesiac<10)
            cout<<"0"<<miesiac<<".";
        else
            cout<<miesiac<<".";
        //wypisujemy rok
            cout<<rok;
    }
    void Czas::Wpisz()
    {
        cin>>dzien;
        cin>>miesiac;
        cin>>rok;
        koryguj();
    }
    void Czas::koryguj()
    {
        if (dzien>31)
            dzien = 31;
        if (dzien<1)
            dzien = 1;

        if (miesiac>12)
            miesiac = 12;
        if (miesiac<1)
            miesiac = 1;

    }
    int Czas::porownaj (const Czas& wzor) const
    {
        if (dzien == wzor.Dzien() && miesiac == wzor.Miesiac() && rok == wzor.Rok())
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }
```

and finally main.cpp

```
#include "Czas.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int flaga=1, flaga2=0;
    Czas data();
    cout<<"1 - Wpisz date\n2 - Wypisz date\n3 - Porownaj\nx - wyjscie";
    while (flaga == 1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        switch (getchar())
        {
        case '1':
            {
                data().Wpisz();
                flaga2=1;
                break;
            }
        case '2':
            {
                if (flaga2=0)
                    cout<<"Trzeba najpierw wpisac date!";
                else
        //          data().Wypisz();
                break;
            }
        case '3':
            {
                if (flaga2=0)
                    cout<<"Trzeba najpierw wpisac date!";
                else
                //  czas().porownaj
                break;
            }
        case 'x':
            {
                flaga=0;
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                cout<<"klawisz nieobslugiwany";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what i have wrong here?

Comment: Did you add Czas.cpp to your project?

Comment: Yup. And problem is solved. Sftrabbit did it ^^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Czas data();
```

This declares a function called `data` that takes no arguments and returns a `Czas`. I think you actually want to default construct a `Czas` object like so:

```
Czas data;
```

Which also means you should remove the parentheses after `data` in this line, since it is not a function:

```
data().Wpisz();
//  ^^ Remove
```

In addition, you'll need to move the default arguments for your constructor up into the header file:

```
    Czas(int dl = 1, int m = 1, int r = 1970);
```

The default arguments need to be visible to any code that includes the header, so that they know they can call it without any arguments.

Comment: Shouldn't VS2010 issue a warning for that?

Comment: @user1764961 No idea, I don't use VS. It could do, but there's no reason it has to.

Comment: if it's implemented that way then it has to. :-)

Comment: It's working! At the begining i was adding parentheses to object, because visual was throwing me an error without them. But after build program, it disappeared!